# how to LogOut in ASP membership

Tags: .net, asp.net

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) //logout
{
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon(); // it isn't logout >_<
    }
}
```

how to logout ? :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using the standard membership providers and forms authentication:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
```

Usually works a treat.

Be aware that if the user presses back in their browser, they will probably see the cached (logged in) version.

**Edit to respond to comment**

I was under the impression that [FormsAuthentication.Signout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx):

> Removes the forms-authentication ticket from the browser.

And that as the *authentication ticket* is completely separate from, and unrelated to the *session token*, if you want to completely clear all knowledge of the user from the server at that point, calling Session.Abandon is a good thing to do. I'm aware that a new session will be created for them on the next page request - I'd be interested to see documentation to the contrary.

Comment: Session.Abandon should not be used while logging off a user. FormsAuthentication.SignOut() should do all the SignOut job.

Comment: I've found that if you don't include the Session.Abandon() call, the role provider pulls the roles for the previously logged in user the next time someone logs in. That's not good.

Comment: @Shea Daniels: "The next time someone logs in" from the same machine? Curious, because the Role provider should be working with the currently logged in user, and the Auth token - How are you calling your role provider?

Comment: The role provider is set up in the web config. It's automatically called after the user logs in and tries to access a page. I'm using the "Authorize" decorators in MVC.

Answer (score 1):

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```

This should log-off the user and take him to Login page.